# ENOENT Error in Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I have just started working with rails and I encountered this error which does not give a lot of detail. Since I am not familiar with ruby on rails, perhaps someone here can help.

The error occurs in the active model serializer for the model.

```
class SecuritySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :ticker, :identifier, :weight
end
```

the rendering occurs as follows:

```
def index
    @securities = Security.all

    render(json: @securities, each_serializer: SecuritySerializer)
  end
```

The error that I get:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C):
app/serializers/security_serializer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/securities_controller.rb:9:in `index'
```

EDIT

I am using 64-bit ruby on windows 8.
I added this to a file called serializer_init.rb in config/initializers

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json_api
```

Comment: Please make sure that you have added `ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json_api` in an `initializer`

Comment: Thanks. I did that and the error is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I was using version 0.10.0. I downgraded to 0.8.0 and removed the initializer. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

User gem from branch master.

```
gem 'active_model_serializers', :git => 'git://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers.git'
```

Comment: USE gem from branch master.